# OpenStack Nova modification

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I know the Structure of Open-stack and the basic idea of how it works. Could someone explain how I would go about modifying the scheduler for nova tho. I was thinking that I could download the code from git-hub then change some code around. The only problem with it is that I can not run anything because of the whole setup with the rest of the modulus. Could someone give me a general high level overview of how or were I could start?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a devstack setup where you can run, test, modify code. Here is a link which can help you get a devstack up.
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NovaVMware/DeveloperGuide